# Real Time text from a file on tkinter window

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have tried so many times with different logics but i failed , can anyone help me please: how to update the tkinter window in real time with data from a txt file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        # ... YOUR widgets here ...
        self.T = tk.Text(self, height=25, width=80)
        self.S = tk.Scrollbar(self)
        self.T.config(yscrollcommand=self.S.set)
        self.T.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y)
        self.S.config(command=self.T.yview)
        self.S.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
        self.updateWidgets()

    def updateWidgets(self):
        with open('realTimeUpdatingTextWidget_Cg.py') as f:
            newText = f.read()
        # ... YOUR code for updating the Widgets ...
        self.T.delete('1.0', tk.END)
        self.T.insert(tk.END, newText)
        self.after(1000, self.updateWidgets)

app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Save the code above in a file `realTimeUpdatingTextWidget_Cg.py` and run it to see the changes if you edit the file in a text editor.

The **TRICK** is usage of a following code structure:

> ```
> class App(tk.Tk):
>     def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
>         tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
>         # ... YOUR widgets here ...
>         self.updateWidgets()
>     def updateWidgets(self):
>         with open('fileWithWidgetsParameters.txt') as f:
>             realTimeFileContent = f.read()
>         # ... YOUR code for updating the Widgets ...
>         self.after(1000, self.updateWidgets)
> app = App()
> app.mainloop()
> ```